# include custom fields in search query

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, search, custom-fields

I am trying to add custom fields to my search, here is my sql query:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'title_filter', 100000, 2 );
function title_filter($where, &$wp_query){
        global $wpdb;

        if(isset($_GET['s'])){            
            $searchWord = trim($_GET['s']," ");
            $searchWhere = "AND ((
                             (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '% $searchWord %' OR wp_posts.post_title LIKE '$searchWord %' OR wp_posts.post_title LIKE '% $searchWord' OR wp_posts.post_title LIKE ' $searchWord' OR wp_posts.post_title LIKE '$searchWord' OR wp_posts.post_content LIKE '% $searchWord %' OR wp_posts.post_content LIKE '$searchWord %' OR wp_posts.post_content LIKE '% $searchWord' )
                            OR 
                            (tter.name LIKE '% $searchWord % ' OR tter.name LIKE '$searchWord %' OR  tter.name LIKE '% $searchWord')
                         OR 
                        (ttax.description LIKE '% $searchWord %' OR  ttax.description LIKE '$searchWord %' OR  ttax.description LIKE '% $searchWord')
                        OR 
                        (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '% $searchWord %' OR wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '$searchWord %' OR wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '% $searchWord')
                       OR
                       (wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '% $searchWord %' OR wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '$searchWord %' OR wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '% $searchWord')

                ) AND 
                wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'reports', 'news-section', 'event-item', 'board-members', 'brand-logos', 'vacancies') AND ( wp_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_posts.post_author = 1 ) )";

    return $searchWhere ;


        }
        return $where; 
    }
```

Before adding this line `OR (wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '% $searchWord %' OR wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '$searchWord %' OR wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '% $searchWord')` my code was working perfectly for searching word from title or content but after adding this line not working, can't understand why, because I guess I wrote right sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found one solution, installed Relevanssi plugin, and also found one trick, wrote it in functions.php and now my custom fields are searchable:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_the_content');
function my_the_content($content) {
relevant custom fields so that relevanssi includes their content (inlcuding the real my content if specified)
  if($post = is_the_content_called_by_relevanssi()){

    $fields = array('customfield2','customfield2'); 
    foreach($fields as $field){
      $field_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field, TRUE);
      $content .= ' '. ( is_array($field_value) ? implode(' ', $field_value) : $field_value );
    } 
  }
  else global $post;  

  return $content;
}

function is_the_content_called_by_relevanssi(){
  if(!function_exists('relevanssi_init')) return false;

  if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.4.0') >= 0) 
    $trace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT, 21);
  else
    $trace = debug_backtrace();

  for($i = 0; $i<min(array(21,count($trace))); $i++){ 
    if('relevanssi_do_excerpt' == $trace[$i]['function']) return $trace[$i]['args'][0];
  }
  return FALSE; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use: pre_get_posts action (in **function.php**)

```
function filter_by_metavalue( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
       $query->set('meta_key', 'YOUR KEY');
       $query->set('meta_value', 'VALUE');
    }}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_by_metavalue' );
```

Comment: I have updated my answer please check @aidaghazaryan

Comment: no success, I have tried in this way: if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if(isset($_GET['s'])){
            $query->set('meta_value', $_GET['s']);
       } 
    } @vrajesh

Comment: ok I have tried without checking request, but again nothing @vrajesh

Comment: no, it is issue because user will search what he want, I don't know exactly what user will search and giving $_GET['s'] to meta_key as value will be wrong right? @vrajesh

Comment: Please print_r $query and exit execution and check sql query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83288/discussion-between-vrajesh-and-aidaghazaryan).